# BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default for Vuetiy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, polyfills

I am trying to use nodemailer for a Vuetify/Vue.js web application that I am making. In the process, I am running into an issue because of webpack v 5. I have looked all over the internet and still have the same issue. Each time I continue to get this same issue. I know you need to include a polyfill, but no where I have looked has been clear on where to do so. There are 3 possible locations to include the polyfill on Vuetify. There is babel.config.js, vue.config.js and there are the webpack.config.js.

I know that your first suggestion will be to put in webpack.config.js. That is where the console is suggesting that it needs to go. But I had to add that file to my project it was not there before. I will include a picture below.

[The user made webpack.config.js as well as the already existing Vue and babel config files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAMv0.png)

[Here is the list of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBU9N.png)

I have done everything that I have been told to do from the console log, but that has not changed a thing. I still get 40 errors. Every source online seems to work with react, but I use Vue. In all of the config files for Vue, Bable and the user made webpack I have done the following.

```
`module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
    }
  }
```

}
`

[Vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfyIi.png)
[User made Webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwnut.png)

Please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong. What was supposed to take at max an hour has turned into six.

Comment: You're running into trouble because you try to use Node lib in browser app, not because of Webpack.

Comment: What do i need to do then because it keeps tell me that I have an issue with polyfills and the internet keeps sending me to webpack

Comment: Use nodemailer on the backend, not the frontend. It's called *node*mailer and not *browser*mailer.

Comment: You need to read something about the difference between a browser (client side)  and Node (server side). You physically can't send a mail from a browser without using a server. If this were possible, any website would be able to use your PC to send spam